# css style is applied to AppBar too late

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have a `View` which contains a `ListView`.
When the view is loaded for the first time, it takes some time to create the ListCells. To prevent the UI from looking blocked, I wrapped the call to `listView.setItems` in `Platform.runLater`,  and set a placeHolder to the listView as an indicator for the loading process.
The views `AppBar` contains a `TextField` and some `Buttons`, which are styled via css-file. While the buttons are styled correctly, the textField first appears with no style applied to it, i.e. colored black, and as soon as the ListView is populated the TextField has its style applied as well.

What could be the reason for this delay?

```
    @Override
    protected void onShowing() {
        appBar.setNavIcon(getBackButton());
        appBar.setTitle(searchField.getTextField());
        appBar.getActionItems().addAll(btnSort, btnFilter, moreMenu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onShown() {
        setItems();
    }

    protected void setItems() {
        if (!firstShow) {
            lview.setItems(items);

        } else {
            if (!items.isEmpty()) {
                lview.setPlaceholder(new Label("loading data..."));
                Platform.runLater(() -> lview.setItems(items));
            }
            firstShow = false;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT :**

It is only -fx-text-fill which is applied after a delay. All other styles get applied  immediately.

```
.app-bar > .title-box > .text-field{ 
    -fx-border-width: 0.0; 
    -fx-border-insets: 0.0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0;
    -fx-font-family: 'Roboto Medium';
    -fx-font-size: 20.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -app-bar-item-color;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: #59819C;
}

.app-bar > .action-items .button{
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
public class AppBarTestApp extends MobileApplication {

    private static final String ITEMS_VIEW = "items";

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {

        addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () ->
            {
                Button btnShowNextView = new Button("Show items view");
                btnShowNextView.setOnAction(e -> switchView(ITEMS_VIEW));

                return new View(HOME_VIEW, new StackPane(btnShowNextView));
            });

        addViewFactory(ITEMS_VIEW, this::loadItemsView);
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/com/jns/appbartest/view/common.css").toExternalForm());
    }

    private View loadItemsView() {
        URL resource = ItemsPresenter.class.getResource("items.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(resource);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fxmlLoader.getRoot();
    }
}



public class ItemsPresenter {

    private static final MobileApplication app       = MobileApplication.getInstance();

    @FXML
    private View                           view;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String>               lview;

    private Button                         btnBack;
    private Button                         btnMoreMenu;
    private TextField                      txtSearch;

    private boolean                        firstShow = true;

    private ObservableList<String>         items = createItems();

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        view.setOnShowing(e -> onShowing());
        view.setOnShown(e -> onShown());

        btnBack = MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_BACK.button(e -> app.goHome());
        btnMoreMenu = MaterialDesignIcon.MORE_VERT.button();
        txtSearch = new TextField("Items");
        txtSearch.setPromptText("search");

        lview.setPlaceholder(new Label("no data to display"));
    }

    private void onShowing() {
        app.getAppBar().setNavIcon(btnBack);
        app.getAppBar().setTitle(txtSearch);
        app.getAppBar().getActionItems().add(btnMoreMenu);
    }

    private void onShown() {
        if (!firstShow) {
            lview.setItems(items);

        } else {
            firstShow = false;
            lview.setPlaceholder(new Label("loading data..."));

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);  //to simulate a long lasting initial creation of listCells
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                lview.setItems(items);
            });
        }
    }

    private ObservableList<String> createItems() {
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String name = "Person #";

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            items.add(name + i);
        }

        return items;
    }
}


<View fx:id="view" id="itemsView" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.jns.appbartest.view.ItemsPresenter">
    <center>
        <MobileLayoutPane fx:id="pneListView">
            <center>
                <ListView fx:id="lview" />
            </center>
        </MobileLayoutPane>
    </center>
</View>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I've created a simple test with a ListView, and I can see the textfield text or prompt text styled correctly before the items show up.

Comment: I've added the code to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

With the code posted, I can reproduce the issue on Android.

Obviously, I take this part:

```
private void onShown() {
    lview.setPlaceholder(new Label("loading data..."));
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);  //to simulate a long lasting initial creation of listCells
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        lview.setItems(items);
    });
}
```

is added to simulate the initial creation of cells.

But precisely it shows what is the issue you are facing: the mock sample shows that on the JavaFX thread (`Platform.runLater`), you are blocking it (`Thread.sleep(2000)`). During that time, the textField text is black, and only later on it gets styled.

If you modify that snippet into this one:

```
private void onShown() {
    lview.setPlaceholder(new Label("loading data..."));
    new Thread(new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);  //to simulate a long lasting initial creation of listCells
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            lview.setItems(items);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

now the heavy task is outside the JavaFX thread, and you can see that the textField is styled immediately.

Back to your real problem: the lesson here could be that you should move out of the JavaFX thread every heavy task and only at the very last moment call it. The `Task` is a good mechanism for doing so.

Comment: In my App I retrieve the items from a cache, which is initialized at the appstart, while a Preloader is showing. It seems the UI is blocked for a while, when the ListCells get created. I was able to improve the speed of initially populating the ListView by setting a fixedCellSize to it, however there remains a noticable delay. Even with the mock example, how is it possible that the buttons have the css applied, and the TextField is styled later?

Comment: If you run it on desktop, you don't even see any node at the AppBar, so the UI is totally frozen. And that's the expected result. On Android it seems it takes more time to start blocking the UI, and during that short time, the nodes are added and partially styled. With this in mind, if you could delay a little bit more the cell creation, you will render the view properly, though it will take more time to complete its full load.

Comment: If I run it on desktop, everything looks fine. AppBar shows all nodes, appropriately styled. For a fast test, I used a PauseTransition to delay the cell creation, which solved the issue. Thanks José. I only wonder what would be the right duration for the delay?

Comment: I've added an `Listener` to the `fillProperty` of the AppBar nodes, which confirmed what you stated in your comment. The nodes are partially styled, until the listView items are set, which interrupts the styling of the remaining AppBar nodes. As a workaround  I add the AppBar nodes in the Presenters initialize method to a throw away Scene, and call applyCss, before the view is showing for the first time.